# при использовании useNavigate ничего не происходит

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

при использовании useNavigate ничего не происходит. Но если убрать то рендериться как нужно, но мне нужно при рендере MailOpen, создавать страницу /mail, чтобы переходить назад
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём проблема и как мне это реализоватьк
соурсы тут https://github.com/nzVoid/UpMail.

Comment: Исправьте ваш вопрос, чтобы код был в текстовом формате, для этого нажмите `Править` под самим вопросом

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую посмотреть это видео про работу с историей и локацией в React-router 6. Мне в свое время очень помогло. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jv0ckzkKYzU&list=PLiZoB8JBsdznY1XwBcBhHL9L7S_shPGVE&index=5

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)